# How to perform a self-join in Apache Flink

Tags: apache-flink, self-join

Usually when performing a self-join on a table one would include a restriction on the ids of the joined table(s) to avoid symmetric results and joins of a row with itself.

There seem to be at least three ways to implement a self-join in apache flink (as mentioned [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-3910)):

1. Use the regular join operator `dataset.join(dataset)`. However the beforementioned restriction does not seem possible to implement this way.
2. Use a `reduce` operator and manually implement the join. Which may lead to memory problems.
3. A combination of `reduceGroup`, `flatMap`, and `reduceGroup`. This approach is used in some gelly implementations of graph algorithms, eg. [JaccardIndex](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-libraries/flink-gelly/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/graph/library/similarity/JaccardIndex.java), where the operations are named `GenerateGroupSpans`, `GenerateGroups`, `GenerateGroupPairs`. It is not clear to me whether these names refer to a certain pattern or computation strategy.

Is there a single best way to perform a self-join in Apache Flink or does it depend on the use case? Which method is best performance-, memory- and reliability-wise? Is there a general pattern to understand method 3?

Comment: SQL self-join is a join where the same value is on both sides. It does *not* mean anything more specific than that. There is nothing against joining a row with itself or a column with itself. What exact condition(s) for self-join are you interested in? PS "inner join on" returns what "cross join where" does.